# getting device fcm token without authentication (laravel)

Tags: android, ios, laravel, firebase, push-notification

I have a web app made by laravel framework and I want to send notifications from my web app to the android and ios versions of my platform, I'm considering using firebase for notifications.

But here is the problem the authentication (registration) is not done using firebase It's done using the web application because users are not allowed to make their own accounts(it must be given to them), now I find my self in a dilemma because if the authentication is not done using firebase I can't get the fcm token, and therefor I can't send notifications.

My question is there a way to get a device's fcm token without having it authenticating using firebase?

And if that is not possible is there any other way to send notifications in the manner i described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing two different things.

1) The user registration with the web site (This happens in you web site/application and has nothing to do with FCM).

2) The registration of the device to FCM done through the google account set on the Android Device.

The way this works is that the device register's to FCM, at that point your app receives a "callback" (`onTokenRefresh()`) from FCM informing you about the new token that was created for the device.

In that callback you call the web site's server and associate the FCM token you received with the account of the user that registered to the website (1). The association would be kept in a table in a database so you can lookup the token by the user id assigned by the web application.

Comment: so you can get FCM token without using firebase authenticaion?